# DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR: canceling statement due to user request

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am using postgresql with pgadmin, I am getting following error

```
DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "TRUNCATE mystats_na_apple.mv_xrx_cal_ids"
PL/pgSQL function mystats_na_apple.ld_mv_xrx_cal_ids() line 9 at SQL statement at line 187.
```

This is the function ld_mv_xrx_cal_ids

```
DECLARE

  err text;
  msg text;

BEGIN

TRUNCATE mystats_na_apple.mv_xrx_cal_ids;

INSERT INTO mystats_na_apple.mv_xrx_cal_ids
SELECT 
  dte,
  win_id,
  user_id,
  agt_name,
  lvl,
  job_code,
  sbu,
  cost_center,
  lob,
  hire_date,
  prod_date,
  sup_userid,
  sup_name,
  om_userid,
  om_name,
  gm_userid,
  gm_name,
  tenure_id,
  tenure_name,
  entity_id,
  genesys_id,
  nt_id,
  iex_id,
  mu_id
FROM dbi_link.remote_select(10,
'SELECT   dte,
  win_id,
  user_id,
  agt_name,
  lvl,
  job_code,
  sbu,
  cost_center,
  lob,
  hire_date,
  prod_date,
  sup_userid,
  sup_name,
  om_userid,
  om_name,
  gm_userid,
  gm_name,
  tenure_id,
  tenure_name,
  entity_id,
  null as genesys_id,
  null as nt_id,
  null as iex_id,
  mu_id
  FROM mystats_apple.mv_xrx_cal_ids
  where dte >= now()::DATE - 45'::TEXT)
remote_select(
    dte date,
  win_id bigint,
  user_id text,
  agt_name text,
  lvl integer,
  job_code text,
  sbu text,
  cost_center text,
  lob text,
  hire_date date,
  prod_date date,
  sup_userid text,
  sup_name text,
  om_userid text,
  om_name text,
  gm_userid text,
  gm_name text,
  tenure_id text,
  tenure_name text,
  entity_id integer,
  genesys_id text,
  nt_id text,
  iex_id text,
  mu_id text
  );


GRANT SELECT ON TABLE mystats_na_apple.mv_xrx_cal_ids TO webusers;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE mystats_na_apple.mv_xrx_cal_ids TO dbi_link;

  RETURN 'Success!';

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN BEGIN RETURN SQLERRM; END;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that the PostgreSQL client sent a cancel request to the PostgreSQL server.

That could happen if you are using the `psql` command line client and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

But perhaps some component on the client side has met a timeout and sends the cancel request.

Comment: I need your help https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/284607/query-returns-different-result-in-postgresql